# A problem about zero derivatives in the weak sense implying zero almost everywhere in $W_{0}^{1,1}$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

In my PDE course, I encountered a problem stated below:

**Exercise.** Suppose that $\Omega \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is an open and bounded domain. Prove that if $u \in W_{0}^{1,1}(\Omega)$ and $\nabla u \equiv 0$ in $\Omega,$ then $u=0$ a.e. in $\Omega$.
Here $W_{0}^{1,1}(\Omega)$ is defined to be the closure of smooth functions of compact support in $W^{1,1}(\Omega)$ in $W^{1,1}(\Omega)$ norm.

I know that zero weak derivatives imply constant almost everywhere in the domain, but I don't know how to see $u=0$ a.e. in $\Omega$ using the assumption that  $u \in W_{0}^{1,1}(\Omega)$.

Is there a convincing proof?

Comment: Try a specific case : does the constant function $1$ belong to $W_0^{1,1}(0,1)$?

Comment: Are you familiar with the trace operator?  $u$ is equivalent to a constant function so, in particular, it is equivalent to a smooth function.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon Yeah, I considered about this. But cannot wrote out a proof. Any idea?

Comment: @PeterMorfe Sorry, I have not leared about this.

Comment: @ScienceAge Can't exactly write it out, but I construct $f_n$ as follows : take $K_n = [\frac 1n , 1 - \frac 1n ]$ then it is possible to construct a smooth function( which we call $f_n$) which is identically $1$ on $K_n$ and $0$ outside $K_{n+1}$. This is called as a bump function. The sequence $f_n$ belongs in $W_0^{1,1} (0,1)$ and I think converges to $1$ in the norm, so $1 \in W_0^{1,1}(0,1)$, which means the question is false . The question probably meant $u$ is constant a.e.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon: No, this is not true. $1$ does not belong to $W_0^{1,1}(0,1)$.

Comment: @gerw So that convergence I mentioned must be failing , probably because of the derivative. I will try to figure out why this does not work. Thank you for the point out.

Comment: @PeterMorfe: The definition of the trace operator needs some boundary regularity, which is not available here.

Comment: @ScienceAge: Did you have heard of Poincare's inequality? It states that $u \mapsto \int_\Omega \|\nabla u\| \, \mathrm d x$ is a norm on $W_0^{1,1}(\Omega)$, which is equivalent to the original norm. This can be proved first for $u \in C_c^\infty(\Omega)$ and extended to the whole space by density.

Comment: Thank you all for explicit answers.

Answer (score 1):

Let's make an example in the one dimensional case $I=(0,1)$. You already know that $u$ has to be constant, we will see that $u=0$ is the only constant possible. Assume not, then there exists a sequence $\varphi_n \in C_c^\infty(I)$ that converges to $u$ in $W^{1,1}$. Without loss of generality we assume $u=1$. The convergence of $\varphi$ to $1$ in $W^{1,1}$ means that $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} ||\varphi_n-1||_{L^1} + ||\varphi_n' -0||_{L^1}=0.$$ In particular, by the positivity of the norm we see that $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} ||\varphi_n'||_{L^1}=0.$$ But since $\varphi_n$ is compactly supported this is not possible. Let's take the following sequence as an illustrating example
$$\varphi_n(x) = \begin{cases} nx, &x\in (0,1/n), \\ 1, &x \in (1/n,1).\end{cases}$$
This function is neither smooth nor compactly supported but it is good enough for the purpose of demonstration (otherwise use tools like mollification to get a compactly supported smooth function). We see that
$$||\varphi_n'||_{L^1} = \int_0^{1/n} n \, \mathrm{d}x = 1.$$ This contradicts the observation made above. We conclude that $u=1$ is not possible. Similarly, we deduce the same for the other constants except $0$.

Summary: Constant functions as for example $u=1$ are not possible in your problem. The problem is that if you want to approximate $u=1$ by a compactly supported smooth function, then the function will be $1$ at most points but since it is compactly supported, it has to be zero somewhere. To get from $1$ to $0$ the function has to change direction, hence the function has a positive gradient. It is not possible to neglect this term. Indeed, if you try try to make the region where you go from $0$ to $1$ smaller, then, as a compensation the gradient gets bigger.

---

Primarily, this answer should give you an intuition why $u=0$ is the only possible answer. See gerw's comment about Poincaré's inequality for a more sophisticated answer.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the issue I had above more explicitly.

Comment: Thanks for an explicit answer.